# I'm trying to get TensorBoard running. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

This is the code I wrote related to TensorBoard:

```
loss_op =tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_train, labels=tf.cast(labels, 
dtype=tf.int32)))

tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss_op)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
write = tf.summary.FileWriter( "/tmp/mnist_logs")
```

When I go to C:/tmp/mnist_logs it is empty after I train the network

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the merged operation (`merged`) in a session and provide the result to the FileWriter. Try something like this:

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
write = tf.summary.FileWriter( "/tmp/mnist_logs")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...
    summary = sess.run(merged)
    write.add_summary(summary)
    write.flush()
```

Comment: What else do I have to execute in the Session? e.g. Training or Evaluation or anything else

Comment: Unless you use eager execution, every tensor operation needs to be executed in a session. So every training and evaluation step needs to be executed in a session.

Comment: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py

This code has no Session or eager execution but still works. How would you implement tensorboard in this code?

Comment: That code uses estimators, which handle the session for you. If you want to use estimators, you need to learn the Estimator API. If you're just starting, I recommend learning the basics of sessions, variables, and placeholders, and then move on to sessions.